# JavaFX NullPointer Exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx

[image: MainWin.java]

[image: Basic.java]

[image]

When i run my app, i was show error this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exmp.ui.UI.nodeEkle(UI.java:48)
    at exmp.ui.Basic.<init>(Basic.java:47)
    at exmp.MainWin.hazirla(MainWin.java:15)
    at exmp.MainWin.<init>(MainWin.java:26)
    at exmp.Start.start(Start.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
```

All works normally but only problem nodeEkle method, when i debug my app i show scene is null, but how? I'm create scene in method;

```
public void gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur(){
    group = new Group();

    scene = SceneBuilder.create()
                        .root(group)
                        .fill(Color.BLANCHEDALMOND)
                        .build();
```

So i try Scene to static > public static Scene scene; but not work i got another error.So how i can solve this problem..

Comment: Posting code as text rather than as screenshots is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the `gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur()` method in the code sample you provided.

`gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur()` is the method which sets the reference to the scene in the UI class.

Because the method is not called, when you try to reference the scene in the `nodeEkle()` method, you end up with a NullPointerException.

One way to handle this is to do a lazy call in `nodeEkle()` =>

```
public final void nodeEkle(Node... node) {
  if (scene == null) {
     gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur();
  }

  ((Group)scene().getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(node);
}
```

There may be better ways to handle it, e.g. add a constructor to the UI class that performs the tasks in `gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur()`, and ensure the UI constructor is invoked from all UI subclasses, but that will depend on your application and what you want to achieve.

In any case, you probably want to ensure that you invoke `gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur()` once and only once for a given UI instance before you try to do anything with the UI components.

Comment: I do not understand, if i dont call gerekliUIVerileriniOlustur() where i define scene group accordion..

Comment: Added some further explanation to my answer.